# Populate Class Object From XML

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I'm having some problem populating given below XML to class, I know how to populate class object from XML(Deserialization) but below XML is tricky for me.

```
<Header>
      <To EmailType="Personal">abc@abc.com</To>
      <From EmailType="Work">abc2@abc.com</From>
</Header>
```

if I create below class, it will only populate the data part of the XML not the attribute,

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Header")]
    public class Header
    {
        public Header()
        {

        }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "To", Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public string To { get; set; }


        [XmlElement(ElementName = "From", Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public string From { get; set; }
}
```

I want to be able to parse & save both attribute & data.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364253/how-to-deserialize-xml-document

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @pm_2 my xml is different then the example you posted, that xml is quite easy to parse & populate.

Comment: What is tricky? What did you try? What does your class look like?

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd thats the question, what should be the structure of the class, as XML-Tag "To" & "From" has Attribute as well as Data in its node without any child nodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming what you want is to deserialize it as something like:

```
public string ToAddress {get;set;}
public EmailType ToEmailType {get;set;} // an enum
public string FromAddress {get;set;}
public EmailType FromEmailType {get;set;}
```

unfortunately, that is not possible with `XmlSerializer`. You would have to have a hierarchical model:

```
public EmailDetails To {get;set;}
public EmailDetails From {get;set;}

...

public class EmailDetails {
    [XmlAttribute]
    public EmailType EmailType {get;set;}
    [XmlText]
    public string Address {get;set;}
}
```

Alternatively, you will have to parse it manually via `XElement` or similar.

Comment: Thanks, Thats exactly what I wanted.